# Can local state be variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Kinda a silly question, but normally I see

```
const [name, setName] = useContext(myContext)
```

but I have code where I want to do something like:

```
var [name, setName] = useContext(myContext)
useEffect(() => {
  if (someCondition)
    name = undefined

  setName(name ?? getName())
}, [name])
```

I always see that the state is labeled 'const', but does that matter? (the above could be refactored such that it doesn't matter, but this question is specifically regarding whether the 'var' vs 'const' practically matters)

Comment: It _can_ but it _shouldn't_. Just use `setName(someCondition ? name : getName()`

Comment: You "can" use `var` or `let`, but it would yield you no benefits as react would not re-trigger its VM-diffing algorithm if you just assign a new value to your variable. you need to use `setName` in order to prompt said diffing algorithm be re-triggered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React generally practices functional programming, in which variables do not get reassigned, and state does not get mutated. Instead, when an update needs to occur, the entire function *runs anew* with the updated values returned by the `useState` (or `useContext`) calls.

In line with this, it usually makes code easier to understand at a glance when variables are declared with `const` - it'll help you remember *this won't get reassigned, instead, the whole function will run again when an update occurs*.

It's not outright forbidden to use `var`, but it could *easily* mislead you if you try to reassign the variable, since it almost certainly won't work as expected - the reassigned variable will only have that "state" of being reassigned as long as that render is active. Once the next render starts, the prior (or updated) `name` returned by `useContext` will be the new `name`, regardless of what `name` was reassigned to.

Best practice would be to avoid reassignment to avoid potentially confusing yourself. If you think you want to reassign a variable, you should probably reconsider and think about the more React way of doing things, which would likely involve setting state instead.

So *state* variables probably should not be reassigned - but other plain (non-React) variables could be, if it helps you implement the logic you need. (like `let count = 4;` or something, where `count` is local to a nested function and doesn't need to be stateful)

Comment: I think all the variables in the 'use...' section are generally understood to work in a particular way, such that modifying them in normal JS won't actually modify their values. If you only use local state throughout (i.e., no global variables), can can be assured that `someVar = 42` will *not* affect data outside the current execution, so to me it's clear. I could see it being confusing if people are intermixing global and local state. I could add 'var localName = name', but it seems so worthless, and could easily lead to *using* the wrong variable in subsequent code.